# Responsive jQuery menu, collapsing last elements into separate menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design

I have a single level navigation list. What I want to do is, on window resize, add a dropdown at the end to display elements that do not fit the window width.

Below an image representation:

[image]

```
var base = this,
                    container = $(base.selector),
                    items = container.find('>li:not(.smallmenu):visible'),
                    count = container.find('>li:not(.smallmenu):visible').length,
                    listWidth = [],
                    added;

            items.each(function() {
                listWidth.push($(this).width());
            });

            function getWidth() {
                var width = 0;
                container.find('>li:not(.smallmenu):visible').each(function() {
                    width += $(this).outerWidth();
                });
                return width + 100;
            }
            function hideLast() {
                var i = container.find('>li:not(.smallmenu):visible').last().index()

                if( $(window).width() < (getWidth()) ) {
                    items.eq(i).hide();

                    if(!added) {
                        $('<li class="smallmenu"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></li>').appendTo(container);
                        added = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            function showLast() {
                var i = container.find('>li:not(.smallmenu):visible').last().index();
                if( (getWidth() + listWidth[i+1]) < $(window).width() ) {
                    container.find('>li:not(.smallmenu)').eq(i+1).show();

                    if((i+2) === count) {
                        container.find('.smallmenu').remove();
                        added = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            $(window).resize(function() {
                showLast();
                hideLast();
            });
```

However this is not working as expected and half-done. I feel like I am heading in the wrong direction.

EDIT: Here is an updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/anteksiler/zyv8f/1/ Resize your browser to get the effect.

Comment: As an advice to obtain more answers: try to create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or something similar where people can play around without making the effort of setting up all the stuff

Comment: Hi @fguillen, here is an updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/anteksiler/zyv8f/8/